# how to remove white color border on ListView

Tags: html, css, listview, jquery-mobile

hi i add listView in Footer

```
     <  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://responsiveslides.com/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
<style>
.ui-btn.ui-btn-icon-right.ui-icon-carat-r{text-align: center;}
        .ui-btn-icon-right:after {
            display:none;
        }
</style>
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="index" style="background-color:#666666;">

      <div data-role="content" class="slideshow">
      ....
      ....
      ....
      </div>
   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer" style="background:#808080;">
        <ul data-role="listview" style="border-width: 0px;">
    <li style="background:#ffffff !important;border:none;"><a href="#" style="background-color: #666666;border-width: 0px;"><span style="color:white">Home | Office | Shop | Industrial | Exterior | Decor</span><p class="ui-li-desc" style="color:white">ENERGY SAVING LED LIGHTS</p></a></li>
            </ul>
      </div> 



</body>
</html>
```

but white color border added  and then i add border-width: 0px; but no use it's again showing white color border 
Please give me any idea about how to remove white color border on ListView

Comment: if white from some other part is overwritting this one..You can add !important along with Opx.

Comment: @Pranav thanks for Reply Please tell me what wrong in my code

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something demonstrating the issue..?

Comment: can you show your entire code

Comment: @user3678584 there is a very limited code, we can make only assumption here.

Comment: @Pranav please look my code and then please give me any idea

Comment: @KheemaPandey thk for reply please look my code and then please give me any idea

Comment: Are you talking about white border between content and listview?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this rule:

```
#footer ul{
 border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

White color is caused because body has margin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://responsiveslides.com/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .ui-btn.ui-btn-icon-right.ui-icon-carat-r {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .ui-btn-icon-right:after {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index" style="background-color: #666666;">

            <div data-role="content" class="slideshow">
                ....
      ....
      ....
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer" style="background: #808080;">
                <ul data-role="listview" style="border-width: 0px;">
                    <li style="background: #ffffff !important; border: none;"><a href="#" style="background-color: #666666; border-width: 0px;"><span style="color: white">Home | Office | Shop | Industrial | Exterior | Decor</span><p class="ui-li-desc" style="color: white">ENERGY SAVING LED LIGHTS</p>
                    </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did your code like this:     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin:0px;
            }
        </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">......

Comment: and add "display:block;" to <a href="#" style="background-color: #666666; border-width: 0px; display:block;">

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in Firefox, Chrome and IE 10 but couldn't see any white border.
I think that your border comes from parent elements not from this part of markup.

Answer (score 0):

you are seeing white line because `background-color:white`  have used in `li.`

```
<li style="background:#ffffff !important;border:none;"><a href="#" style="background-color: #666666;border-width: 0px;">
```

By changing the `background-color` your white line disappear.

> **Note:**  It would be good instead of putting all item in single `li`; put each item on each `li`.

Comment: IS this answer helpful for you?